# How to fix SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed:

Tags: ruby, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-5

I am adding multiple guests to a guestlist by importing an excel spreadsheet.

It originally was a standalone resource and everything worked perfectly. I was able to import a new guestlist as well as reimport an updated guestlist.

I have now nested my guestlist model in my event model so that a event has many guestlists and a guestlist belongs to an event and I am now getting a contraint error when importing the spreadsheet.

I have, to my knowledge, made the correct changes to my files for the nesting and also reset my database and run db:migrate. The first import worked but then threw the error when reimporting the same file (this worked on the origninal)

Old Controller:

```
 def import
    Guestlist.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to guestlists_path, notice: "Guest-list 
  Successfully Imported."
   end
```

New Controller:

```
 def import
  @guestlists = @event.guestlists.import(params[:file])
  redirect_to event_guestlists_path(@event), notice: "Guest-list Successfully Imported."
end
```

Import Method:

```
def self.import(file)
  spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file.path)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    guestlist = find_by(id: row["id"]) || new
    guestlist.attributes = row.to_hash
    guestlist.save!
  end
end
```

Save Method:

```
def save
    if imported_items.map(&:valid?).all?
      imported_items.each(&:save!)
      true
    else
      imported_items.each_with_index do |item, index|
        item.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          errors.add :base, "Row #{index + 1}: #{msg}"
        end
      end
      false
    end
  end
```

Guestlist Schema:

```
  create_table "guestlists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "firstname"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "response"
    t.integer "event_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "dietary_requirements"
    t.string "lastname"
    t.index ["event_id"], name: "index_guestlists_on_event_id"
  end
```

If any more code is needed I will add accordingly!

Thanks in advance

Error Log from terminal:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: guestlists.id: INSERT INTO "guestlists" ("id", "firstname", "email", "created_at", "updated_at", "lastname") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)):

app/models/guestlist.rb:20:in `block in import'
app/models/guestlist.rb:16:in `import'
app/controllers/guestlists_controller.rb:34:in `import'
Started POST "/events/1/guestlists/import" for ::1 at 2019-10-05 13:19:03 +0200
Processing by GuestlistsController#import as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"UmBvaiHr3s2HJ4WKxBazfRNtVT1E5BLrejPjLhx1IbrlGshEbE8UcaQIilJJeq2m3rGefDtJ65C0iRToZWvOqA==", "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe42d188080 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/sw/t3c38b_d0z343xcp6sznp_h80000gn/T/RackMultipart20191005-44877-kiw9l6.xls>, @original_filename="guestlists (7).xls", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"guestlists (7).xls\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n">, "commit"=>"Import Guest List", "event_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (2.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/ryan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  Event Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/guestlists_controller.rb:111
  Guestlist Load (2.6ms)  SELECT  "guestlists".* FROM "guestlists" WHERE "guestlists"."event_id" = ? AND "guestlists"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["event_id", 1], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/guestlist.rb:18
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/models/guestlist.rb:20
  Guestlist Create (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "guestlists" ("id", "firstname", "email", "created_at", "updated_at", "lastname") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["id", 1], ["firstname", "ryan"], ["email", "ryan.neill11@gmail.com"], ["created_at", "2019-10-05 11:19:04.522415"], ["updated_at", "2019-10-05 11:19:04.522415"], ["lastname", "neill"]]
  ↳ app/models/guestlist.rb:20
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  ↳ app/models/guestlist.rb:20
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 243ms (ActiveRecord: 12.8ms)
```

Comment: How looks your `db/schema.rb`?

Comment: @mechnicov I added above

Comment: Remove constraints ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that now you are calling import on a relation that is scoped to a specific event `@event.guestlists.import(params[:file])`.  In your import method it tries to find a record like this:

`guestlist = find_by(id: row["id"]) || new`

If the guestlist isn't attached to your event, but one exists attached to a DIFFERENT event, it won't find it here, because `self` in this context refers to your relation `@event.guestlists`, not the `GuestList` class.  If one exists on a different event, it will still try to create a NEW guestlist using an ID that already exists in the database.

This is why you get a uniqueness violation on the id:

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: guestlists.id`

When you previously were calling `GuestList.import`, the context for `import` was the `GuestList` class, so `find_by` in that context means `GuestList.find_by`, and your list will always be found and it won't try to create a new one when one already exists.